# Word 2013 - Vertical axis title - text to display vertically

Tags: microsoft-word, axis

It seems that this is the correct StackExchange site for posting a simple Word2013 Q. If not, please let me know.

I have searched everywhere and can not find an answer.

In Word2013 I can not for the life of me find the option to make the primary vertical axis text of a chart to display vertically:

- L
- i
- k
- e
- T
- h
- i
- s

I actually hate this look, but it is for a uni assignment with specific instructions.
Any help is appreciated (it used to be simple with Word2010).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I got:

1. Select Chart Tools --> Format --> "Format Selection" button.
2. In the subwindow, select "Text Options."
3. Change text direction to "Horizontal."
4. Insert carriage returns after each letter.

[image: Word 2013 with vertical chart axis with vertical letters]

Comment: Good work around mate, cheers.